# AWS IAM - Read Only Access Policy for SWF Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-swf

I'd like to grant a group read-only access to an entire SWF domain. The users in this group will be able to see all workflow instances and the events / activities history of each workflow. They will not be able to create workflows, activities, or start workflows.

Can someone post an example of what the policy document JSON for this would look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

So follow the wizard, I generate the policy with all list `Actions`, which you can add/delete depend on your own request.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1420410404486",
      "Action": [
        "swf:ListActivityTypes",
        "swf:ListClosedWorkflowExecutions",
        "swf:ListDomains",
        "swf:ListOpenWorkflowExecutions",
        "swf:ListWorkflowTypes"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```